# Changing the type of some column names in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I'm working with the following data frame :

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['USA','UK','France','Germany'],
        2006.0:[1,4,5,6],
        2007.0:[5,4,8,5],
        2008.0:[4,8,4,7]})
```

I'd like to change the column names that are floats to integers, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this using `isinstance` to check datatype and convert the float type objects to int. Then reassign the column names.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['USA','UK','France','Germany'],
        2006.0:[1,4,5,6],
        2007.0:[5,4,8,5],
        2008.0:[4,8,4,7]})

data.columns = [int(i) if isinstance(i, float) else i for i in data.columns]
print(data)
```

```
   Country  2006  2007  2008
0      USA     1     5     4
1       UK     4     4     8
2   France     5     8     4
3  Germany     6     5     7
```

You could use a `df.rename(columns = {"old name": "new name"})` to handle only specific column renaming but that would just overcomplicate the problem.

---

**EDIT:** Another approach with a `boolean mask` and `df.replace`, seems complex though.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['USA','UK','France','Germany'],
        2006.0:[1,4,5,6],
        2007.0:[5,4,8,5],
        2008.0:[4,8,4,7]})

mask = data.columns.str.isnumeric()!=False
#[False  True  True  True]

g = {k:int(k) for k,v in zip(data.columns, mask) if v==True}
#{2006.0: 2006, 2007.0: 2007, 2008.0: 2008}

data.rename(g, axis=1, inplace=True)
print(data)
```

```
   Country  2006  2007  2008
0      USA     1     5     4
1       UK     4     4     8
2   France     5     8     4
3  Germany     6     5     7
```

Comment: So there's no way to do this using a boolean mask ? I've been trying to do that but it seems like many attributes of Series aren't available for index objects

Comment: Can you add your approach to the question? I am not sure what you mean by `using a boolean mask`. Maybe that would help me understand. Maybe you could elaborate. Of course there are multiple ways of doing this.

Comment: Series.str.isnumeric() for example that tests if the elements of the Series that are 'str' contain numeric values and returns a Series object with True or False. This Series can then be used to change the values that verify the condition

Comment: It's kinda the same that's happening here. However, there are only 2 ways of changing column names. `pd.rename()` and `df.columns`. First one needs a dict with specific old and new names and second one needs the complete list of names.

Comment: Mmm i see, i was trying to do something like `df.columns[df.columns.isnumeric()] = df.columns[df.columns.isnumeric()].astype('int')` but i guess i'll have to it manually.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the `boolean mask` approach that you are talking about but it seems to be more complex.

Comment: Couple of things.. `df.columns.isnumeric()` wont work you need `df.columns.str.isnumeric()`. Also, even though u can filter for only the numeric type columns and change them to int, you will still have to either append the other columns back if you will use `data.columns` approach OR you will need to create a dictionary if you are going to use the `df.rename` approach. I have shown both in my answer. Feel free to pick and choose. Let me know if this solution helped you.

Comment: Yeah thank you, your answer was helpful. I'm just trying to play with the code and look for better ways to do things. I'll let you know if happen to find a better approach

Comment: Sure, do mark the answer incase you find these to be equivalent or better.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to reassign

`data.columns = ['Country', 2006, 2007, 2008]`

```
   Country  2006  2007  2008
0      USA     1     5     4
1       UK     4     4     8
2   France     5     8     4
3  Germany     6     5     7
```

Comment: This is just an example, i might have a database with way more columns