# Reshape a pandas dataframe so that items in a column are new column titles?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, transpose

My data file has to be in columns to export to excel because of its size, and therefore I have to transpose it when I'd like to use it again in python. I would like to rotate the dataframe. How can I make items in the left column into column headings for a new dataframe?

````
import numpy as np
#example 
example_raw = [["Date", "11/19/20","12/22/20","2/17/21","2/19/21"],
       ["Time","9:40:28","9:25:13","9:20:17","9:19:58"],
       ["ID", 101, 102, 206, 104], 
             ["timestamp", "09:40:28:590","09:25:13:437","09:20:17:455","09:19:58:629"], 
             ["SECOND", np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],
             [0, 4.69, 4.1, 7.17, 8.66],
              [0.2, 4.67, 4.16, 7.17, 8.74],
              [0.4, 4.66, 4.21, 7.17, 8.75],
              [0.6, 4.66, 4.21, 7.17, 8.75],
              [0.8, 4.64, 4.28, 7.16, 8.75]]
example_table = pd.DataFrame(example_raw,columns=["Unnamed: 0", "CURRENT","CURRENT.1", "CURRENT.2", "CURRENT.3"])

#Desired outcome
desired=[["11/19/20","9:40:28","101", "09:40:28:590",4.69,4.67,4.66,4.66, 4.64],
         ["12/22/20","9:25:13","102", "09:25:13:437",4.1,4.16,4.21,4.21, 4.28],
         ["2/17/21","9:20:17","206", "9:20:17:455",7.17,7.17,7.17,7.17,7.18]
        ]

desired_table = pd.DataFrame(desired,columns=["Date","Time", "ID","timestamp", "0","0.2","0.4","0.6","0.8"])```




This question response would be applicable if the seconds data was not in the way. 
It gets me close, but not quite there. 
```new_table_1 = example_table.set_index([example_table['Unnamed: 0'],example_table.groupby('Unnamed: 0').cumcount()]).drop('Unnamed: 0',1).unstack(1)```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
df_result = example_table.dropna().T
df_result.columns = df_result.iloc[0]
df_result = df_result.iloc[1:].rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_result)

       Date     Time   ID     timestamp     0   0.2   0.4   0.6   0.8
0  11/19/20  9:40:28  101  09:40:28:590  4.69  4.67  4.66  4.66  4.64
1  12/22/20  9:25:13  102  09:25:13:437   4.1  4.16  4.21  4.21  4.28
2   2/17/21  9:20:17  206  09:20:17:455  7.17  7.17  7.17  7.17  7.16
3   2/19/21  9:19:58  104  09:19:58:629  8.66  8.74  8.75  8.75  8.75
```

Comment: you are a treasure. Thank you!!

Comment: I notice that later, I get a message that gives me: DtypeWarning: Columns (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
Later on, I really need the columns to all have floats; ie 0 needs to be 0.0, later when there are more columns, 1 needs to be 1.0. How can I correct this given what you have said?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64995455/changing-the-type-of-some-column-names-in-a-data-frame
mask = df_result.columns.str.isnumeric()!=False
#[False  True  True  True]

g = {k:int(k) for k,v in zip(df_result.columns, mask) if v==True}
#{2006.0: 2006, 2007.0: 2007, 2008.0: 2008}

df_result.rename(g, axis=1, inplace=True)

Comment: Gives me the error: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: @zob First of all, before conversion of the column labels to integer, I would like to know some background information before we can decide what to do is the best. 1) what's the further intended action you did that got the error ? 2) If you need the column labels to be float numbers, how about if they are float number in string format ? That is, instead of 0.2 (numeric format), we have '0.2' (string format), is this ok for you ?

Comment: @zob If you are ok to keep the numeric column labels as string, you can use the code `df_result.columns = df_result.columns.astype(str)` Let me know whether this works for you. Note that you cannot convert the float number column labels to integer because all your columns 0.2, 0.4 etc. will be converted to the same label 0. This is undesired for multiple columns to have the same column label.